# Problem with aria-expanded="true"/aria-expanded="false" scraping with selenium using python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I´m using selenium to do webscrapping to download a text in the html. I can log in, but there is a window which I have to click to show the link I need to click

[Once I click on Comercios the "consultar" menu shows, not before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Autn.png)

I´ve tried this:

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='enlace1']")))
driver.find_element(By.ID, "enlace1").click()
```

And I get this error:

```
TimeoutException: Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    (No symbol) [0x0090DCE3]
    (No symbol) [0x008A39D1]
    (No symbol) [0x007B4DA8]
    (No symbol) [0x007E019F]
    (No symbol) [0x007E03AB]
    (No symbol) [0x0080EE62]
...
    (No symbol) [0x008BC63B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x767C00F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77497BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77497B8E+238]
```

Also tried this:

```
enlace1=driver.find_element(By.ID,"enlace1")
enlace1.click()
```

And get this error:

```
NoSuchElementException
(No symbol) [0x008BC63B]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x767C00F9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77497BBE+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77497B8E+238]
```

I think selenium is not reading the JS part in the code.

The HTML i see is this:

[This is part of the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2vIR.png)

```
<li class="nivel1 ui-accordion-li-fix">
        <a class="nivel1 ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-active ui-corner-top" id="enlace1" href="" role="tab" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>Comercios</a>
        <ul id="menu1" class="nivel2 ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom ui-accordion-content-active" role="tabpanel" style="display: block;">
            <li class="nivel2">
                <a class="nivel2" id="enlace1_1" href="" onclick="cargarJava('/odin-war/odin/comercios/query.html');return false;">Consultar</a>
            </li>
```

How can I click on id="enlace1" to deploy the id="enlace1_1"?

Being enlace1 Comercios and enlace1_1 Consultar.

PS: I´ve checked a lot of entries with similar problems, but can´t find a solution. Please let me know if I didn´t find the right one.

Thanks in advance

I´ve tried lo locate the item with ID, XPATH, CSS, CLASS. I need to click there to deploy the next window and send me to the next one after I click in the second one.

EDIT:

I couldn´t call that body, but once logged in I could go to the next window with the second URL, I don´t know if it´ll work for someone else. I don´t know if it didn´t work bc the html changed the aria-expanded and the class elements once I clicked there.  But If I send the driver to the url I go if I clicked in the desired botton it works...

Once in the second window I could call the body, and latters frames to finish my scrapping. Thanks @JeffC for the idea, worked in the second window, because the web was built really bad.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the element is not in an IFRAME?

Comment: I answer with another comment with the html, but I tried to move from the iframes and not works

Comment: please do not share image code errors